# React-native MobX @observable is always undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx

`globalStore.js`

```
import {observable} from 'mobx';

export default class globalStore {
    @observable loggedIn = false;
}
```

Followed by main `App.js`:

```
import LoginForm from './src/components/LoginForm';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import globalStore from './src/store/globalStore';
```

which renders loginForm:

```
      return (
            <LoginForm store={globalStore} />
      );
```

In `LoginForm`, I wish to access the "loggedIn" observable:

observer

```
class LoginForm extends Component { / ... 

render() {
        console.log(this.props.store.loggedIn);
```

Result: `undefined`

Desired result: `false`

Why does this not work?

Do I need a Provider wrapping the `LoginForm` component? How come?

Wrapping my entire  in the `App.js` in a Provider with the store does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are few things from my point of view I've doing differently with a working implementation:

First you need to create new store from your `GlobalStore`. I've done it this way:

```
class GlobalStore {
  @observable loggedin = false;
  ...
}

const store = new GlobalStore();
export default store;
```

Then you should use provider:

```
import GlobalStore from './path/to/stores/GlobalStore';

<Provider
  globalStore={GlobalStore}
>
  <AppRelatedContainers />
</Provider>
```

Finally you should inject your store in login form:

```
@inject('globalStore')
class LoginForm extends Component {
...

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.globalStore.loggedIn);
    ...
  }
```

With these steps you should end up with a working solution. I know MobX can be pain in the ass when you work with it initially. But then it eases up and you're good to go :).

Comment: I actually learned MobX a year ago... Apparently I have forgot. And yes, pain in the ass at first, but i'm getting the gist of it again. THanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see the instance of your global store class

try

```
import {observable} from 'mobx';

class globalStore {
    @observable loggedIn = false;
}
const global_store=new globalStore(); // as a singleton class
export default global_store;
```

then your login form will be like below

```
 return (
            <LoginForm store={global_store} />
      );
```

or may be you can instantiate it on your login form as well